# Equivalent EMF of unequal cells connected in parallel

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, voltage, batteries

I'm aware of the formula to calculate equivalent EMFs of 2 cells connected in parallel as shown in the top figure. But what happens if we switch the polarity of one of the cells? Shouldn't the equivalent EMF change in accordance with Kirchhoff's Voltage Law? [image]

Comment: Although connecting cells of unequal emf in parallel may inspire exercises such as this one, it's to be avoided in practice as it runs the cells down even without any load connected.

Answer (score 0):

If $E_2$ is larger than $E_1$, the lower diagram would have

$$E=\frac{-E_1r_2+E_2r_1}{r_1+r_2}$$

in accordance with KVL because it is just reversing the polarity of $E_1$. The derivation is the same as the upper diagram just change $E_1$ to $-E_1$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Could you clarify what you mean by the lower circuit? I'm assuming you're talking about the circuit that the two cells are connected to.

Comment: @student The lower circuit means your second diagram, reverse polarity one. Sorry for ambiguity.